# QT5 mouse Plugin not loading with qtwebkit

Tags: plugins, qt5

I have cross compiled QT5 for MIPS based embedded platform. There is no pointer device. Hence created "Socket based" pointer device by modifying the evdevmouse plugin and it is working.

But when I try to run "QtWebkit", it never tries to search or load this plugin. I am not sure what is the difference. (It loads image/ eglfs etc other plugins except this).

Can any one suggest way to go around?

EDITED: QtWebkit is "QtTestBrowser" application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "But when I try to run "QtWebkit", it never tries to search or load
>   this plugin"

Finally I found the reason.
Due to some changes which we had done in the application, there was small corruption in argv, and hence it was not finding “-plugin” properly.

I enabled the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS, and found that it was not trying to load that at all and then found the reason.